# Using External Wait class to pause execution of javascript functions

Tags: javascript, multithreading, wait

I am trying to figure out how to pause execution of a function before calling another function while making my javascript code extremely readable. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
function main_function(){   
   function a();
   // wait for function a to finish - could take 1 second - could take 3 seconds

   function b();
   // wait for function b to finish - don't know how long this will take

   function c();
   // completed
}
```

I have read dozens of articles on how to use setTimeOut, redirects to other functions, callbacks, etc. but was unable to find a solution that really worked well (and most of them just use a clunky setTimeout(), which really doesn't help since I have no idea how long each function might take).

So, I finally came across a small utility called "WaitThread.js". This seems to be exactly what I am needing to do and it seems like it would be something that is easy to read and maintain later on.

However, I can't figure out how to use it!  :)

Would anyone be able to provide me an example of how to use this WaitThread.js? Or at least provide me with a readable/elegant way of waiting for javascript functions to execute one after another while waiting for each one to finish first?

**Here is a link to the WaitThread.js page:**

http://www.robertmayo.com/blog/2006/07/htmljavascript-wait-for-asynchronous.html

Thanks!

Comment: That solution really isn't magical or anything. All it does is poll for a change in some condition with a watchdog timer.  In a web browser, there's no such thing as "waiting" with JavaScript code. The only way to approach the problem is by embracing the asynchronous programming model.

Comment: Also, it would help in providing some explanations and suggestions if you'd go into more detail about what these functions are doing, and what it is that makes them take a long time.

Answer (score 1):

According to the explanation for waitthread.js, it just uses a timer to poll, waiting for the change of the value of some variable.

The more typical design pattern for this type of problem uses callbacks and `function a` will call a callback when it's work is done which will kick off `function b`.  So, you pass a function to `function a` which should be called when `function a` has finished it's work.  The more complete design pattern usually has a callback for both a successful exit and an unsuccessful exit and may even pass parameters from the exit, but since I don't know your specifics, I haven't tried to model that here.  For a multi-step process, it would look like this.  We assume that three asynchronous functions exist as functions a, b and c and each takes a function as an argument that will get called when the asynchronous function is complete:

```
function main_function_step1() {
  a(main_function_step2);
}

function main_function_step2() {
  // execute code here that goes after function a, but before function b
  b(main_function_step3);
}

function main_function_step3() {
  // execute code here that goes after function b, but before function c
  c(main_function_finish);
}

function main_function_finish()
{
  // execute whatever code here to finish
}
```

The more complete solution would pass an object with a success callback and a failure callback and would provide at least a parameter to each function so results or error conditions can be returned.

In that case, it would look like this:

```
function main_function_step1() {
  function main_function_a_step1_fail(err)
  {
    // handle error in step 1
  }
  var o = {success: main_function_step2, fail: main_function_a_step1_fail};
  a(o);
}

function main_function_step2(data) {
  // execute code here that goes after function a, but before function b
  function main_function_a_step2_fail(err)
  {
    // handle error in step 2
  }
  var o = {success: main_function_step3, fail: main_function_a_step2_fail};
  b(o);
}

function main_function_step3(data) {
  // execute code here that goes after function b, but before function c
  function main_function_a_step3_fail(err)
  {
    // handle error in step 3
  }
  var o = {success: main_function_finish, fail: main_function_a_step3_fail};
  c(o);
}

function main_function_finish(data)
{
  // execute whatever code here to finish
}
```

This is a little messy to code, but it requires no polling or global variables.  If there's no code to execute between the steps and the logic between them is all the same, you can parameterize everything in a data structure and execute all the steps with a single function that just executes one item out of the data structure and passes the next values as callbacks and so on.

Comment: jfriend00 - Thanks for the feedback! This does look pretty good. However, it still looks to be a bit messy (as you noted in your comment). Would you be able to provide me with an example of how to use the WaitThread.js file so I could see how it would work and then possibly later on I could modify it to adhere to your model that you have shown here. Thanks!

Comment: Pointy - what the function does is call a java app that scans an ID card. While this is going on, the script needs to wait. When it is done (i.e. when an image file actually exists) it then uses another javascript wrapper around a java applet that FTP's the image up to a server. After this is completed, it then parses the data from the scanned license. I know PHP and C# very well. However, javascript (I should say - advanced javascript) is a little new to me. It is taking me a bit to get my head around the fact that I can't call a script and wait for it to be done, then call my next script.

Comment: I can do this if I am calling an ajax call (i.e. calling to a PHP file to do some processing) however, I am not able to do this when just calling internal javascript functions (one to another).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know the waitThread library.  I'm likely to start using YUI3 AsyncQueue: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/async-queue/ myself to make this type of code more readable/maintainable.